# Discontinuity of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $(0;1)$ and 0 everywhere else on $\mathbb{R}$
take also an enumeration $\{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the rationals on $(0;1)$. And define $g(x):=\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x-r_n)}{2^n}$, Is this function discontinuous on every x of $(0;1)$ and unbounded on any interval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds that for $k\in \mathbb{N}$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(r_k+1/n)\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^{-k}f(r_k+1/n-r_k) =2^{-k}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(1/n)=\infty$$

It follows that $g$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore you can sow that

$$\forall z\in Q,N\in \mathbb{N}, \epsilon>0\  \exists x\in U_{\epsilon}(z): g(z)>N$$

based on that one can also prove that the function is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$

The function is *not* unbounded on the Interval $[0.5;0.5]$

Comment: You must mean that for any $x\in (0;1) \epsilon >0 N \in \mathbb{N}$ one can find $r_n$ sufficiently close to $x$ and then $g(r_n + \frac{1}{k}$ with $k$ sufficiently large so that $r_n + \frac{1}{k}$ is in $(x-\epsilon;x+\epsilon)$ and and $g(r_n + \frac{1}{k})$ is bigger than $N$. so that makes g discontinuous at $x$. This also proves that its is unbounded on any interval, THANKS

Comment: Is that a known function ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know the function. To be precise: $f$ is unbound on all intervals containing more than one element